# How to Specify fonts for Text fields using muPDF

Tags: c++, pdf, mupdf

I am using **muPDF** library to add fields in existing PDF Documents.
I have successfully added a checkbox by defining its appearance.

But **Text Fields** are a problem as they need a **Font Resource**.
I cant figure out how to add fonts in a PDF document.
muPDF does have functions that deal with fonts, but I am unable to use them in a proper manner.

So i need to know how to load a font in a PDF document and how to reference them to my Text Field in the default appearance(DA).

----------------------------------------------------------EDIT------------------------------------------------------------------

Currently I am using the function **pdf_set_free_text_details** in pdf-annot-edit.c
But it only sets the predefined fonts . i wish to use other fonts as well

If this is not the right place to ask this question, then please if somebody could redirect me to the correct place. MuPDF only has a bug report site as far as i know.

Answer (score 2):

Pass any of the font types specified on pdf-font.c as a string.
For eg: "Courier", "CourierNew", etc..

Comment: can anyone explain me about how to modify mupdf for adding text. How to use pdf_set_free_text_details method